# What can I do to avoid ResourceWarnings relating to subprocess use in an IsolatedAsyncioTestCase?

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, subprocess, python-asyncio

I'm learning async in Python and have the following (simpified) test in python 3.9.7:

```
class TestBasics(IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    async def test_server_basic_json(self):

        # Set up a server
        server = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-u', f"{SOURCES_ROOT}/backend/server.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)  # gives the server a chance to get going so we can connect to it

        # ... connections would be created and tested here

        async def terminate():
            # connections closed here
            server.terminate()

        return await terminate()
```

This code yields the following result:

```
(rpwrr) rpwrr $ python -m unittest tests/test_basics.py 
/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py:1052: ResourceWarning: subprocess 2320249 is still running
  _warn("subprocess %s is still running" % self.pid,
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
/usr/lib/python3.9/unittest/async_case.py:102: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=6>
  ret = await awaitable
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 1.071s

OK
```

How can I eliminate these ResourceWarnings? I'd like to "enable tracemalloc to get object allocation traceback" if it is useful but I've not been able to discover how to do that.

The subprocess is terminated successfully in that it is not running when I check it after the test completes.

The async is redundant in this simplified case but the connection testing that the test is ultimately for makes extensive use of awaitables.

I don't think the server itself is relevant to the problem but here it is just in case:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

from backend.configuration.websockets import SERVER
from backend.database.watchable_database import WatchableDatabase
from backend.event import send_event, decode_event
from backend.event_processor import EventProcessor


class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.database = WatchableDatabase()
        self.event_processor = EventProcessor(self.database)
        self.websockets = set()

    async def __call__(self, websocket, path):  # called for each connected websocket
        await self.register(websocket)
        try:
            async for event in websocket:
                print(f"< event: {event}")
                await self.event_processor(websocket=websocket, **decode_event(event))
        finally:
            await self.unregister(websocket)

    async def broadcast_client_count(self):
        for ws in self.websockets:
            await send_event(ws, 'client_count', content=len(self.websockets))

    async def register(self, websocket):
        self.websockets.add(websocket)
        await self.broadcast_client_count()

    async def unregister(self, websocket):
        self.websockets.remove(websocket)
        await self.broadcast_client_count()


async def serve():
    print(f"serving on ws://{SERVER['host']}:{SERVER['port']}")

    async with websockets.serve(Server(), **SERVER):
        await asyncio.Future()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(serve())
```

The WatchableDatabase and EventProcessor objects do not currently open or close any files (the database is a placeholder dictionary at the moment).